# Does 'neighbour', as a verb, take a direct object?

Tags: american-english, british-english, direct-objects

I heard, today, on an American documentary, the word 'neighbour' used as a verb, something I had not come across before. The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/125924?rskey=oswNwb&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) tells me that the verb is obsolete or rare, but seems to have come back into fashion, regionally, in the US - of course in the AmE spelling of 'neighbor'.

Apparently it is also used, regionally, in the north of England and in the English midlands (though I have never heard it, myself, in England).

The OED examples seem to indicate that the verb merely means to 'act in a neighbourly way' towards individuals or the close community.

I would rather like to use the verb (now that I have found it) with a direct object. 'Before he passed away, I neighboured him.'

Is it used with a direct object in AmE ?

Comment: I've never heard it. Maybe it's coming back because this is the 50th anniversary of Mister Rogers' Neighborhood.

Comment: That's not what [neighbor](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=neighbor) means in the U.S. today—that usage may be in the OED, but I've never heard it. The usage I'm familiar with is *"New York neighbors on Pennsylvania."*

Comment: @PeterShor The way it was used in the documentary was 'we don't neighbour' meaning, we keep ourselves to ourselves. No direct object.

Comment: That must be a regional usage. Where was the documentary set? It's not in the [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=neighbor), so it's probably not General American. I'd interpret its meaning in your example "Before he ..." sentence as "lived close to".

Comment: @PeterShor If I remember correctly the speaker was from Denver, Colorado.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you use it.  As a verb, it has both transitive and intransitive definitions.

See headings "verb (used with object)" and "verb (used without object)" in the following link:

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/neighbour?s=t

Note that the entry begins with spelling, definitions, and usage examples for American English.  It then provides spelling, definitions, and usage examples for British English by scrolling down until you arrive at the heading "British Dictionary definitions for neighbour."

Comment: Yes, my 1959 Webster's Dictionary gives both transitive and intransitive verb definitions. So it may be used in a main clause with a direct object.